# Linux C read file line by line

Tags: c, linux

How to code a read file line by line in linux C?

In windows C++ I use ifstream.

I dont know about linux, please advice?

Okay chill out guys, don't down so much.

here is the code:

```
char fpath = "file.txt";
char names;
FILE *fp;

ifstream fs(fpath);

while (fs >> names)
{
  // here is some buffer to send to a server.
}
```

So here I need to read each line from file.txt and send each of those to a server.

Comment: I have tried ifstream. but i dont know what library thats from for linux?

Comment: @user1553142 not "on linux" or "on windows" - it's standard C++, it's linked by default (on any reasonable implementation).

Comment: @user1553142 `#include <iostream>`

Comment: C on linux :) like the title says.

Comment: To expand on @effeffe comment you've tagged this [c], but `ifstream` is a c++ interface not present in c.

Comment: like i said, i dont know what is the function for C. I know on C++ I can use ifstream. :)

Comment: So, why people suggest you C++ features, and why you try those features? Google _"read a file C"_ or something like that to find tons of examples, then come back here (but I think this won't be necessary anymore).

Comment: @user1553142: Is there any particular reason to use C in Linux? Not that there's something wrong with this. It just sounds, like you think you should use C in Linux and C++ was something reserved for Windows, or something like that. If that's not the case, better rename your question "How to read a text file line by line with C, as compared to C++ ifstream".

Comment: I'm just testing out linux and i dont have c++ compiler on it. So im stuck with C. any advice? would be really great if i can get a c++ compiler on the linux machine im using.

Comment: @user1553142: I'm pretty sure that you have a C++ compiler installed. The GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) ships with a C++ frontend and C++ libraries by default for ages. Try out if you've got the programm `g++` available; that's the C++ frontend of GCC.

Comment: It's easy to install a C++ compiler like g++, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux you have the POSIX library available, so you want to use [`getline`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `fgets` function in the standard C library reads a line, both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Please don't use or recommend `fgets` expect for fixed format files; for free format files use `getline` if you have POSIX, or use a included implementation of `getline` or something equivalent if you don't.

Comment: I don't see a problem with `fgets`. It's safe in that it never overruns the allocated buffer. It won't read the whole line if it happens to be too long, but it's an open question how you want to treat very long lines. You might not want a gigabyte to be allocated on the heap by `getline` when reading a file in a completely unknown format.

Comment: On the whole your right that it is safe and I *was* recoiling from plain ole `gets`, but if you don't know how long the lines are you have to add a bunch of cruft to deal with the *"Oh, wait. We haven't gotten to the end yet"* case. The complete solution is to implement an incremental parser, but `getline` is relatively easy and robust as long as your memory holds out.

Comment: Anyway, without knowing what OP wants to achieve, this is but speculation.

Answer (score -1):

> In windows C++ I use ifstream.

*ifstream* is part of the C++ standard library and not bound to any operating system. ifstream works in Linux just as it does in Windows.

Comment: Except that he insists he's working in c.

Comment: This is not the answer... this is not an answer at all.

Comment: @effeffe Teachers in Universities confuse C, and C++ they think it's the same, maybe that's why he is confused also.

Comment: @effeffe: I think, OP does not really know (yet) what he wants. Does he want to read a file line by line with C as he can do with C++/ifstream; or does he wonder how to do it in Linux and somehow fell for the misconception that he was forced to use C for this.

Comment: @effeffe: Well, not at my university ;) All the teachers giving programming courses do know the differences very well on my Uni.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto: not in computer science courses

Comment: @datenwolf: sure OP is confuse, and first (wrong) comments confuse him even more. I just think that for these thing a comment is enough. Anyway, last comment wasn't mine :)

Comment: @effeffe: Sorry, about that, indeed I intended to address Alberto.